# Why do I get a login prompt when posting a comment to Serverfault?

Tags: support

I've experienced over the past few weeks that if I start a comment and pause some time (3-5 mins maybe) before posting to ServerFault, that I get a login prompt from the server (modal pop-up) and cannot continue. I usually copy my comment, refresh the page and re-post it successfully.  What's happening?

FWIW, this is happening with a current rev of Chrome.

[image]

Comment: Hmm, can you grab a screenshot? If you're talking about the "You must be logged in" banner that rolls down from the top of the screen I've never had that happen -- It might be a problem with your cookie vanishing (did you enter/exit porn mode?) or something that makes the Stack Exchange system think you've signed out.

Comment: It is not that - it is the plain webserver login prompt that one get's when the web server is doing the authentication not the app. I'll see if I can reproduce at will

Comment: what browser?  I never get modal dialogs in stackoverflow

Comment: added a screen shot above

Comment: Just to be clear, are you seeing this modal window when you try to comment on a "main" SF post, or a Meta SF post? (Or both?)

Comment: Is it a MITM attack?  Are you sure you don't have a proxy or anything evil in between you an SF?

Comment: We do have a proxy, but the password prompt is from serverfault.com, not the proxy.  Also, I do not see this will all SO sites.  It didn't happen here on meta for instance

Comment: I dun never seen it do ***THAT*** before. ::scratches head and waits for the developers to come::

Comment: If you have reason to pause for 3 to 5 minutes before posting maybe you should reconsider your comment. It is just a comment after all, not a technical dissertation.

Comment: Sometimes @John, life & work interrupt, tho.